# Generated Javadoc files not found in project

Tags: java, eclipse, ide, javadoc

I am looking for a way of making the documentation of my custom Java library accessible **offline** (not hosted on remote control services). So I started generating the Javadoc, which output a `/doc` folder with `.html` doc files in it. Good.

However, when I include this library in another project, the documentation is not found even though the project was exported with source files. I ended up trying to locate it manually and even though my IDE (Eclipes in my case) claims that the location is valid, it still state that no Javadoc is attached.

[image: Javadoc location]

My question is, **how to make this Javadoc available offline in the jar file for the developers using my library?**

Comment: When exporting the jar, you can configure that sources and/or javadoc is exported, too

Comment: As it is said in the question, the jar I exported is packed along with source files. Thus, the `/doc` folder **is** in the jar file. There is no mention specifically related to Javadoc. See [here](https://i.imgur.com/Q4V6Y3g.png).

Comment: If you use gradle, you may want to generate a javadoc jar using gradle...

Comment: Both, exporting with source and attaching Javadoc works for me. Why is the Javadoc not found in your case, even though the project was exported with source files? Please provide an example and a detailed step-by-step instructions on how to reproduce this issue.

Comment: @dan1st Not sure it will fix anything :/

Comment: @howlger First, [generate the Javadoc files](https://i.imgur.com/lwtCK6K.png). Then, export the project as jar file with sources like [that](https://i.imgur.com/Q4V6Y3g.png). Finally, import the jar file in another project, `Build Path > Configure Build Path > Add External JARs` like [that](https://i.imgur.com/6lE7tK3.png). It prints me [this](https://i.imgur.com/7VhQcoa.png) when hovering my library methods and fields.

Comment: @HugoBOIS _"Note: This element neither has attached source nor attached Javadoc and hence no Javadoc could be found."_ is displayed if the JAR contains the source, but the element has no Javadoc and the source is not explicitly attached (like it is the case in the screenshot shown in your question). Show what will opened if you right-click and choose _Open Input_.

Comment: @howlger I agree with you, but that's what I'm trying to display. I'm not sure what you mean about right-cliking and choosing input, maybe [that](https://i.imgur.com/nldxGnT.png)? If so then it just prints my library main class `.class` file.

Comment: @HugoBOIS I meant right-clicking in the Javadoc view, but I guess _Open Declaration_ in the hover will do the same.

Comment: @howlger Then as in my previous comment, it just opens my library main class `.class` file if I click on *Open Declaration*. :(

Comment: @HugoBOIS Sure, but will the source code or the bytecode be shown. The issue is probably that the sources (`.java` files) are missing in the JAR, located in a different folder or do not have everywhere Javadoc comments, not that the sources are overlooked in the JAR on the Java Build Path. I have tried to reproduce it in Eclipse 2020-06, but everything works as expected. Please show the comment that should be shown and what's in the JAR.

Comment: @howlger Sorry for late answer haha. Thank you for your comment but since then, I switched to IntelliJ and it completely works, problem is gone. I don't know why Eclipse does not display it and is unable to handle it, but well (not that surprising given the few things this IDE handles correctly haha).